# Discrepancy with Firefox print (headers and footers)

Tags: firefox

Ubuntu desktop 12.04 LTS on a Dell PC.

Created 2 user accounts. Both are Administrator.

User u1, when printing in Firefox (a WEB site), print options work. Specifically, headers and footers to get page # of #, title, URL, etc.

User u2, same operation. Print options not working - does not print requested headers and footers (page # of #, title, URL). It prints, but does not apply the requested options.

Same target printer (Brother HL-3075CW, via USB)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem with a printer setting that I missed earlier.

Checking "Scale to Fit" did the trick - apparently, Firefox was sending the header and footer information to be printed, but the pages were scaled larger that a sheet of paper, so did not appear.

Enabling "Scale To Fit" solved the problem.